# Different behaviour when calling thread.isInterrupted and printing the result

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupted-exception

I am bit confused with the behaviour of `thread.isInterrupted` in the program below.

```
public class ThreadPractice {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Starting thread..." + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                    System.out.println("Waking up");
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    System.out.println("Thread is interrupted!!!");
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
        });

        t.start();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        t.interrupt();
        //System.out.println(!t.isInterrupted());
        while(!t.isInterrupted()){
            System.out.println("Current thread not interrupted!!!");
        } 
    }
}
```

When executing the above program as such, it prints,

```
Starting thread...Thread-0
Thread is interrupted!!!
```

But when I uncomment the `System.out` statement to print the interrupt status, it runs into an infinite loop printing "Current thread not interrupted"

I am not able to figure out exactly what difference `System.out` statement makes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that I don't always get an infinite loop.

I suspect it is due to the interleaving of operations. It helps to also check if the thread is alive:

```
System.out.println("Current thread not interrupted!!! Alive? " + t.isAlive());
```

If the thread is not alive, its interrupted status is false.

I get an output like:

> Starting thread...Thread-0
>   Thread is interrupted!!!
>   Current thread not interrupted!!! Alive? true
>   Current thread not interrupted!!! Alive? false
>   [infinite loop]

I guess the first loop sees the thread not interrupted because the `InterruptedException` has removed the flag - then you reset the flag with `interrupt()` in the `run()` method and the thread can finish and is not alive any more.
The next loop check sees it not alive and you start an infinite loop.

---

An interesting variation can be obtained by adding:

```
System.out.println("Exiting Thread!!!");
```

At the end of the `run()` method - it provides a delay long enough for the loop condition to be checked between the time the interrupted flag is reset and the time the thread dies.